# My Script Inserts users into a database and hashes the password, I need to know how to prevent SQL injection with Procedural-Oriented MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

My script works but I just want to know how I can protect myself from SQL injection with Procedural Oriented MySQLi. Most of the tutorials are about Object-Oriented MySQLi and I'm not familiar with it and don't want to have both Procedural and OO MySQLi in the same script. I have a lot more PHP files. I also do know how to protect against SQL injections but not with procedural style. I know that OO is more useful and A LOT better but as I said I'm not familiar with it. Any help would be appreciated but preferably Procedural Oriented MySQLi.

PHP

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
    
     
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
         
         die("Couldn't connect to the database. try again later.");
         
     } 
 
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

      if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
          
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          
      }

        $signupButton = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $termsandconditions = "";
        $payment = "";
        $creatorAccount = "";
        
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
          $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
          $password = signupform_input($_POST["password"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['signupButton'])) {
          $signupButton = signupform_input($_POST["signupButton"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['termsandconditions'])) {
          $termsandconditions = signupform_input($_POST["termsandconditions"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
          $payment = signupform_input($_POST["payment"]); }
            
          if(isset($_POST['creatorAccount'])) {
          $createrAccount = signupform_input($_POST["creatorAccount"]); }
        }

        function signupform_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
    

        $usernameError = "";
        $passwordError = "";
        $termsandconditionsError = "";
        $error = "";
        $insertPlan = "";
        $updatePassword = "";
        $hash = "";
        $one = "";
        $paymentError = "";
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          
            if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
            $usernameError = "Username is required.";
            echo $usernameError;
          } else {
            $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]);
          }
          if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $passwordError = " Password is required.";
            echo $passwordError;
          } else {
            $password = signupform_input($_POST["password"]);
            $updatePassword = signupform_input($_POST["password"]);
          }
            
        if(isset($_POST['loginActive'])) {
          if($_POST['loginActive'] == "0" && $usernameError == "" && $passwordError == "" && $termsandconditionsError == "") {
              
              $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY username = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."' LIMIT 1"; 
              $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
              if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    
                  $error = "That username is already taken.";
                  echo $error;
              } else {
                  $one = "1";
                  $hash = password_hash($updatePassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                  $insertPlan = $_SESSION['playerPlan'];
                  echo "<p style='color: green'>Hi</p>";
                  $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `plan`, `creatorPlan`) VALUES ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hash)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $insertPlan)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $one)."')";
                  mysqli_query($link, $query);
                  $_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($link);
                 
            
              } 
          } 
            }
        } 
        
?>
```

Comment: You must never sanitize a user's password.  Why are you checking `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` twice?  What if the submitted username is 10 spaces (no visible characters)?  Why `BINARY`?  I recommend prepared statements; forget those old escaping techniques.  `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` is going to keep overwriting itself.

Comment: Why are you declaring SELECTing the whole table to begin with?  Switching from `mysqli`'s procedural syntax to its OO syntax is not a hard task.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not familiar with OO syntax and I learned MySQL the procedural way

Comment: I originally learned the procedural way, then I taught myself the OO way.  I can tell you from experience that the differences are not many and the benefits are several.

Comment: What are some benefits?

Comment: Less verbose code, more professional/modern looking code, and it puts you on the path to using more object oriented syntax elsewhere in your code (where it is appropriate).

Comment: So if I switch my queries right now would I just have to replace underscores with -> or what?

Comment: pretty much yes. it's literally changing underscores to arrows and getting rid of useless repetitions  when the word mysqli or stmt is typed twice. nothing really to talk about

Comment: Well then is there a way to protect me with SQL injections with the code I have right now(procedural).

Comment: I don't think I'll want to convert this procedural mysqli into object-oriented mysqli because I really want to move on.

Comment: How about I just have procedural for variables and links and other stuff that's not revolving queries and use OO for queries. It would work but look disorganize but it doesn't matter because nobody else can see my PHP and sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overview

### OOP vs Procedural `mysqli`

Firstly, it's important to note that the difference between the two methods is the way in which you, as a developer, interact with them. They both *use* use OOP one just hides it behind a veil of *procedural functions*. In fact, you can mix and match:

```
// OOP
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
}

// Procedural
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table");
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    print_r($row);
}

// Combined
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table");
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Secondly, reference your concern about having procedural and OOP in the same code: there's nothing wrong with this. In fact I would argue it's a good thing. Code should be maintained, optimised, and refactored; the process of which takes time and can be done in small chunks. Today you improve your registration system, tomorrow maybe the login(?), and by next year you'll have upgraded everything and be ready to start all over again with PHP 8.x!

The reality is that *best practice*, available functionality, etc. is constantly changing and your code should change to reflect this.

Having said all that Procedural vs OOP is a style choice. Use what you prefer - but know that if you use procedural you're making life *slightly* more difficult for yourself and anyone who inherits your code base.

### Error handling

**General**

You initialise a whole bunch of individual error variables in the form `$errorName = "";`. The problem here is that now you have to remember them all to use them! Additionally although you've initialised the variables you only "set" them later on, so what's the point?

If you must do it this way then I suggest you at least use an array so that all `errors` are grouped together and can be passed as a whole:

```
// Initialise the error array
$errors = [];

// Check username is present and add error message if necessary
if(!$username){
    $errors[] = "Username required";
}

// Check for any errors
if(count($errors)){
    // Some errors were found...
} else {
    // Error free so far...
}
```

Alternatively, if you're interested in learning more about OOP implement a basic error reporting class which you can re-use across your webpages.

**MySQLi**

You don't appear to have turned on error reporting for `mysqli`; which you should aim to do so that you can catch any errors/bugs down the road.

### Prepared Statements

There's really no excuse not to be using prepared statements for SQL queries. There are a number of benefits for both security, simplicity, and readability: with very few downsides.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = " . sanitizeString($username) . " AND status = " . sanitizeInteger($status);

// Becomes...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND status = ?";
```

It's a regular occurrence that people are advised to move toward `PDO` and ditch `mysqli` entirely as well; for comparison:

```
// Prepared statement with Procedural mysqli
$query  = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "si", $username, $status);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Preapred statement with OOP mysqli
$query  = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("si", $username, $status);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$row    = $result->fetch_assoc();

// Prepared statement with PDO
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$username, $status]);
$row   = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Again, there's no harm in having `PDO` and `mysqli` in the same code... Eventually you'll refactor all of the code and it will be uniform.

Changing from one to the other doesn't take as long as you might think either. A number of the methods are similarly named: after all, for a query/result to work, with any method, you have to input and output the same information.

### Misc. Points

**Typos**

You have an error in one of your variable names:

```
 $createrAccount = signupform_input($_POST["creatorAccount"]);
       ^
```

**Code formatting**

At first glance your *generous* use of `if` statements look as though they are all nested inside one another... They aren't, but having the braces `{}` positioned as you do just makes it a bit awkward to read, stick to the standard:

```
if (condition) {
    // Do something...
} elseif (condition) {
    // Do something else...
} else {
    // Do something else...
}
```

You have a few **really** long lines in your code... This makes it confusing to read, especially if the lines break at non-optimal places. You might consider intentionaly breaking lines to make it clearer:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `plan`, `creatorPlan`) VALUES ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hash)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $insertPlan)."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $one)."')

// Becomes...

INSERT INTO `users`
    (`username`, `password`, `plan`, `creatorPlan`)
VALUES (
    '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."',
    '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hash)."',
    '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $insertPlan)."',
    '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $one)."'
)
```

**Code Placement**

It is almost always preferred to have your functions defined at the top of the document. If you define them *somewhere* in the middle of the document they get lost. I, for instance, had no idea what `signupform_input` did until stumbling across it.

**Variable names**

*`$one` what is that? Aside from the fact that you set it to `1` I have absolutely no idea!*

It's good practice to make your variable and function names meaningful: ideally so that other people (and yourself when you come back to the code in a couple of months) understand what they do/contain/mean wihtout having to try and figure out the code or looking around the document. In your case names like `$username` and `$password` are obvious but names like `$link` can be ambiguous. Much better to use names which makes it clear what they are to anyone reading the code. For example:

```
$link                 >>> $mysqli              // Because it's a mysqli object
signupform_input(...) >>> sanitizeInput(...)   // Because the function sanitizes the input
```

Bringing this briefly back to *errors*: you have named a whole bunch of errors reasonably well (`$usernameError`, `$termsandcontitionsError`) and then you have a random `$error`. To me that looks like a *general error condition* but in reality it is actually there to note when the username already exists in the database. Changing it's name would make that much clearer.

Other than that you should be aware that you re-use a few variable names. Especially when it come to queries and result sets. There's potential for confusion here and, if the code were more entangled/complex, there's the possibility you could overwrite something prematurely. If the *bland names* (e.g. `$query` and `$result`) were inside of a function then it doesn't matter so much (assuming they're used once only) because readers are already aware of scope; but having multiple occurrences and overwrites in any one body of code is not a good idea.

---

## Updates and Changes

### Redundant Code

There is a significant percentage of your code that, well, doesn't seem to do anything **or** is repeated later in the code...

This query just executes and does nothing with the result set:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

}
```

Anything to do with `$creatorAccount`, `$payment` & `$signupButton` is halted after the input is *sanitized*. Which means the related errors are also, kind of, pointless?

*Terms and Conditions* has a few variables (including error variables) and `if` statements but it never actually does anything: the code never actually checks whether T&C are set.

Every sigle input is *sanitized* with `signupform_input` at least twice, for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]); 
}


// And...

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $usernameError = "Username is required.";
    echo $usernameError;
} else {
    $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]);
}
```

Additionally, you don't actually use the *sanitized* `$username` in either of your queries! You put it through mysqli's escape function instead.

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])
```

You don't need to use a `LIMIT` in your query when you simply are checking if there are any records. Not least becasue there should only ever be a maximum of one match.

There's no need to check the `REQUEST_METHOD` because you explicitly get the `POST` variables. There's definitely no need to check it twice!

I'm not sure (but concerned) with regards to what `$_POST["loginActive"]` is actually referencing? If it's checking that the user is logged on, shouldn't that be some `SESSION` variable anyway?

Your banks of `if` statements can largely be reduced or removed entirely:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]); 
}

// Becomes...

$username = signupform_input($_POST["username"] ?? null);
```

Some of your *larger* `if` statements just aren't needed. For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['loginActive']))          // Is basically (or could be) redone in the next line of code

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") // As already covered
```

I'm not sure what the point in having `$password`, `$updatePassword`, and `$hash` is?

Your comparisons are *odd*. You frequently use the `==` comparison operator in your `if` statements. Nothing wrong with that; however, you then do things like:

```
$_POST['loginActive'] == "0" && $usernameError == ""

// However, that is effectively the same thing...

"" == "0" == 0 == false == null

// You may as well just do...

!$_POST['loginActive'] && !$usernameError
```

### Missing Code

**Data Validation**

I would suggest that you should be scrapping your function `signupform_input` for a few reasons:

1. We don't want to inadvertently *edit* people's passwords

   - *John* always starts and finishes his password with a `space`; now his password is 2 characters shorter!
   - *Sophie* uses a random password generator which includes `\`; now her password is shorter as well!
   - Bear in mind that if you edit the password on registration you then have to be certain to do the same edits on loin as well. If you don't Sophie and John won't be able to log on!
2. It is typical for sanitizing functions like `htmlspecialchars` to be carried out on output and the *raw data* be stored in the database
3. The function is solely about sanitizing data and not validating it

However, you should implement a couple of new functions

1. To validate the username

   - For example: to make sure it only contains letters and numbers (or whatever characters you so allow)
2. To validate the password

   - For example: to make sure that it is 8 characters long and contains at least one number and one letter etc.

**mysqli Error Reporting**

You should add error reporting for `mysqli` so that you catch and report errors that occur in an appropriate manner:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

---

## Updated Code

### Notes

I'm not 100% sure on a few aspects of your so bear in mind:

1. `$_POST["loginActive"]`

   - I'm not sure what this is and am a little worried it's some kind of "I'm logged on" marker?
   - Have removed from the below code for the time being...
2. `$_POST["termsandconditions"]`

   - I assume this returns a `1` if it has been *checked*?
3. Any other code highlighted earlier to be *redundant* has been removed
4. Some basic rules for username and password validation have been incorporated
5. The below code uses OOP methodology
6. Error messages are printed after the execution of the code, not during.
7. The validation functions are deliberately simple - I don't know what your *rules* are
8. I've added an anonymous class to handle error reporting; it's something you can expand on should you so wish.
9. The logic below consists of approximately half the lines of code of the original

   - Not including the functions and class: because they are new functionality

### Code

***Disclaimer:** Please note that this code is untested*

```
<?

session_start();
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("****", "****", "****", "****");


$error = new class {
    public  array $active  = [];

    private array $message = [
        "usernameRequired" => "Username is required.",
        "usernameTaken"    => "That username is already taken.",
        "passwordRequired" => "Password is required.",
        "termsRequired"    => "You must accept the T&Cs to create an account",
    ];

    public function count() : int
    {
        return count($this->active);
    }
    
    public function throw($messageid) : void
    {
        $this->active[] = $this->message[$messageid];
    }

    public function __toString() : string
    {
        $errorMessages = '';
        foreach($this->active as $error){
            $errorMessages .= $error . "<br>";
        }
        return $errorMessages;
    }
};

function validateUsername(?string $username) : ?string
{
    return preg_match("/^\w+$/", $username) ? $username : null;
}

function validatePassword(?string $password) : ?string
{
    return preg_match(
        "
        /
        (?=.*[a-z])
        (?=.*[A-Z])
        (?=.*[0-9])
        (?=.*[!£$%&@#])
        ^(.{8,})$
        /x
        ", $password
    ) ? password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) : null;
}

$username     = validateUsername($_POST["username"] ?? null);
$password     = validatePassword($_POST["password"] ?? null);                
$terms        = (int) ($_POST["termsandconditions"] ?? null);

$insertPlan   = $_SESSION['playerPlan'] ?? null;
$creatorPlan  = 1;

if (!$username) {
    $error->throw("usernameRequired");
}
if (!$password) {
    $error->throw("passwordRequired");
}
if ($terms !== 1) {
    $error->throw("termsRequired");
}

if ($error->count() === 0) {
    $usernameSql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM users 
        WHERE username = ?
    ";
    $usernameQuery = $mysqli->prepare($usernameSql);
    $usernameQuery->bind_param("s", $username);
    $usernameQuery->execute();
    $usernameQuery->store_result();

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        $error->throw("usernameTaken");
    } else {
        $insertSql = "
            INSERT INTO users
                (username, password, plan, creatorPlan)
            VALUES 
                (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ";
        $insertQuery = $mysqli->prepare($insertSql);
        $insertQuery->bind_param("ssss", $username, $password, $insertPlan, $creatorPlan);
        $insertQuery->execute();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $mysqli->insert_id ?? null;
        echo "Success!";
    }
}

// Output any errors
echo $error;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Procedural Prepared Query Structure

This is the typical layout of a prepared query, in a procedural setting:

```
$sql    = "...";
$query  = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "si", $stringValue, $integerValue);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

The key points are that you:

1. Don't need to carry out your own custom sanitization or use functions like `mysqli_real_escape_string`
2. Use `mysqli_prepare` instead of `mysqli_query`
3. Bind the parameters based on whether they are `string` or `integer`
4. Exceute the query after building it with `prepare` and `bind`

### Updating your code

**`SELECT` Query**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username = ?
"; 

$query  = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $_POST["username"]);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    $error = "That username is already taken.";
    echo $error;
}
```

**`INSERT` Query**

Note: this assumes that `$insertPlan` and `$one` are always integers.

```
$sql  = "
    INSERT INTO users
        (username, password, plan, creatorPlan)
    VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
";

$query = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ssii", $_POST["username"], $hash, $insertPlan, $one);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
$_SESSION["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119630/discussion-on-answer-by-steven-my-script-inserts-users-into-a-database-and-hashe).